# tee to 2 blocks of code?

Tags: solaris, pipe, tee

I am trying to use the tee command on Solaris to route output of 1 command to 2 different steams each of which comprises multiple statements.  Here is the snippet of what I coded, but does not work.  This iteration throws errors about unexpected end of files.  If I change the > to | it throws an error Syntax Error near unexpected token do.

```
todaydir=/some/path
baselen=${#todaydir}

grep sometext $todaydir/somefiles*

while read iline
tee
>(
# this is the first block
do ojob=${iline:$baselen+1:8}
   echo 'some text here' $ojob
done  > firstoutfile
)
>(
# this is the 2nd block
do ojob=${iline:$baselen+1:8}
   echo 'ls -l '$todaydir'/'$ojob'*'
done  > secondoutfile
)
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "`while`" should begin (and end) *inside* each `>( ... )` substitution, not outside.  Thus, I believe what you want is:

```
todaydir=/some/path
baselen=${#todaydir}

grep sometext $todaydir/somefiles* | tee >(
   # this is the first block
   while read iline
   do ojob=${iline:$baselen+1:8}
      echo 'some text here' $ojob
   done  > firstoutfile
  ) >(
   # this is the 2nd block
   while read iline
   do ojob=${iline:$baselen+1:8}
      echo 'ls -l '$todaydir'/'$ojob'*'
   done  > secondoutfile
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `tee` command will do that. The `tee` command will write stdin to one or more files as well as spit it back out to stdout. Plus I'm not sure the shell can fork off two sub-processes in the command pipeline like you are trying. You'd probably be better off to use something like Perl to fork off a couple of sub-process and write stdin to each.